# View geospatial data on Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana-6

In elasticsearch I memorized a series of documents having the following structure:

```
    {
      "_index": "logstash-2018.05.10",
      "_type": "doc",
      "_id": "VM-QSWMBq8te9tFe-bcj",
      "_version": 1,
      "_score": null,
      "_source": {
        "location": {
          "lat": 42,
          "lon": 12.5
        },
        "@timestamp": "2018-05-10T10:20:24.988Z",
        "port": 53950,
        "tags": [
          "geoinfo"
        ],
        "host": "gateway",
        "@version": "1",
        "message": "{\"@version\":1,\"level\":\"INFO\",\"logger_name\":\"it.test.elk.ELKTestApplication\",\"appName\":\"docker-elk-master\",\"thread_name\":\"main\",\"message\":\"LAT: 42, LON: 12.5\"}\r",
        "type": "java"
      },
      "fields": {
        "@timestamp": [
          "2018-05-10T10:20:24.988Z"
        ]
      },
      "sort": [
        1525947624988
      ]
    }
```

The corresponding index is this (I only show a small part):

```
{
  "logstash-2018.05.10": {
    "aliases": {},
    "mappings": {
      "doc": {
        ...
        "properties": {
          ...
          "geoip": {
            "dynamic": "true",
            "properties": {
              "ip": {
                "type": "ip"
              },
              "latitude": {
                "type": "half_float"
              },
              "location": {
                "type": "geo_point"
              },
              "longitude": {
                "type": "half_float"
              }
            }
          },
          ...
          "location": {
            "properties": {
              "lat": {
                "type": "float"
              },
              "lon": {
                "type": "float"
              }
            }
          },

          ...

        }
      }
    },
    ...
    }
  }
}
```

On Kibana -> Coordinates Map, I tried to show the geospatial information contained in the location field, but nothing is seen.
Maybe location should be a geo_point?

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In the Discover view, if the field appears with a ? next to it (or it doesn't have a globe next to it), it means that Kibana doesn't know it's a geo_point (even if Elasticsearch does).  To fix that, you need to go into kibana index settings (for `logstash-*`) and hit the refresh button.

After you've hit reload, type location into the search box on the index definition screen and make sure it shows up as a `geo_point`.